# Removing Windows Technical Preview from Windows Update

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-preview

Windows 10 Technical Preview question, running Windows 7 as my base OS.

Before I noticed the .iso files that were available, I ran an .exe from the Microsoft preview website that apparently configured my Windows Update to download an update called "Update for Windows." If I open Windows Update, it asks if I want to "Upgrade to Windows Technical Preview." I do not want this update now that I have the .iso to virtualize.

If I try to hide this update, it reappears! I want to get rid of that update, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need to do is uninstall **KB2990214**

Just navigate to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features`

[image]

then click on `View Installed Updates`

[image]

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_tp-winipp/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-upgrade-to-windows/ff93402f-22d6-49f8-8893-f4a03002c6d8)

- *I don't have it installed so its not listed*

Comment: I'm basically waiting for Windows Update to confirm, but yeah this looks like the right answer.

Comment: Why don't you just try it, you can view the details of the update, and confirm yourself

Comment: I did, I'm just waiting for Windows Update to return to normal. It's been "checking for updates" for the last few hours.

Comment: I'll leave one last note: You'll need to restart once or twice after removing the update to get Windows Update back to normal.

Comment: The serial downvoting of my highly accepted answers is getting a ridiculous.  If you have a problem with something I have said, come talk to me in chat, don't serial downvote me on `Stackoverflow` and `Superuser` **its just going to get reversed anyways.**

Comment: I don't have KB2990214 on my machine, but I do have KB3044374 which should be the same thing according to the Microsoft Support site. I uninstalled it multiple times but it comes back after some days...

Answer (score 6):

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2990214
```

I did not have it listed under **'view installed updates'**. 

Running command above will uninstall it from your machine if present.