# Windows technical preview installed over my Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-preview

Out of the blue I got a BSOD, on restart I checked to see what the issue was, at one point I ended up at Windows Update. It said I couldn't update and got a error code 80070490. I restarted once again and this time it said I needed Windows update but just 1, so I did it and after 30 minutes, my system now starts in Windows Technical Preview. I have no clue how this happened and no clue how to fix it. No restore points show up, and I have to get back to my Windows 7 for work. Some of my desktop items stayed while others are no longer there and active. I need to know what my options are.

Comment: Sounds like at some point you started the upgrade process to the technical preview of Windows 10.  Your only real option is to complete the upgrade.

Comment: I [suspect](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-delivering-windows-10-windows-update-windows-7-users) you signed up for the Insider Program and then downloaded the required file to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There's possibly a solution [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/820047/removing-windows-technical-preview-from-windows-update) 
It's basically running this from a cmd prompt: `wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2990214`

pakjebakmeel's comments: 
I did not have it listed under 'view installed updates'. 
Running command above will uninstall it from your machine if present.

It's a slightly differnt problem but it will show which KB to uninstall