# Unable to upgrade to Windows 8.1/10

Tags: windows-8.1, updates, windows-10-preview, windows-8.1-upgrade, windows-8-upgrade

After installing recent Windows Updates the Windows Upgrade assistant fails to detect my Windows 8.1 version (previously it was able to get past this point).

This error appears in Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 installers:

> Sorry, we're having trouble determining if your PC can run Windows (8.1/10). Please close Setup and try again.

[image]

[image]

**Troubleshooting**:

1) Rolled back Windows Updates.

2) Disabled third-party startup programs, services and antivirus.

3) Detached secondary hard drives and USB devices.

4) Performed system files "Disk Cleanup", System File Checker and DISM Image Cleanup.

5) Attempted to install with USB, mounted ISO and physical DVD.

The problem persists!

**Log Files:**

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62131673/Docs/Logs.zip

Comment: If you use a Windows 8.1 installation disk does it work?  Just use the Windows 8.1 generic key that matches your version of Windows 8 then once installed changed your key to the actual key that should be used.  If you need more then a workaround, there should be a log file that is generated which contains the reason and the error, that would need to be provided to us.

Comment: @Ramhound unfourtunately that is not an option:
http://i.imgur.com/ryQgO8C.png

Comment: That isn't what I meant.  Your suppose to use the installation media while within Windows which is the only way to get an in-place upgrade.  Its possible your hardware simple isn't supported by either operating systems unless you have in the pass ran them.

Comment: As mentioned "Attempted to install with USB, mounted ISO and physical DVD." They all return the same error, the Setup doesn't even get to the  "Insert key" step.

Comment: Well the picture you provided me saying it didn't work was when you booted to the disk.  Without the log file I can only assume your hardware isn't supported by Windows 8.1 nor Windows 10 which is entirely possible since Windows 8.1 added require x86 instructions and Windows 10 still requires those instructions to be supported.  In the animated gift you don't seem to select the option to download the updates, I assume, you generated these?

Comment: The option to upgrade was available prior running Windows Updates. Also there's no possible way to upgrade Windows using the bootable media alone. The screenshot provided is pretty much universal in that regard.

Comment: Did you happen to install the update that allows the Windows 10 installation to ran?  I suspect the problem is your system is basically prepared to be updated to both `Windows 8.1` and `Windows 10` the first thing I would do is remove the [Windows 10 installation update](http://superuser.com/questions/820047/removing-windows-technical-preview-from-windows-update) and see if you can install Windows 8.1

Comment: I am more then aware its not possible to perform a in-place upgrade if you boot to the installation media.

Comment: share the log files

Comment: Log files here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62131673/Docs/Logs.zip

Comment: @Ramhound No special updates installed, only the suggested Windows Updates, plus they all have been removed while attempting to fix this problem.

Comment: those are the wrong logs. I need the setup logs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824819.aspx Also post a @ myusername to notify me that you replied to me.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There is nothing in the `Windows > Panther` Folder, chances are the error message is not even considered as a failed event by the Setup.

Comment: look here **C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther** for panther logs

Comment: @magicandre1981 [Panther logs here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62131673/Panther.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update because Windows fails to detect the amount of free space on the hidden SYSTEM Partition which contains the bootloader:

```
2015-03-28 20:02:47, Error                 CONX   ConX::Compatibility::CSystemAbstraction::GetDiskFreeSpaceW: Failed to retrieve disk space info for [gle=0x00000003]
2015-03-28 20:02:47, Error                 CONX   CFreeSystemPartitionDiskSpaceChecker failed. Failed to determine the free disk space on the system partition. . HRESULT = 0x80070003[gle=0x00000003]
2015-03-28 20:02:47, Error                 CONX   ConX::Compatibility::CCompatibilityHost::SetScanResult: Compat scan from provider wsc:setup: failed. HRESULT = 0x80070003
```

Error `0x80070003` means that a path is not found:

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80070003
# for hex 0x80070003 / decimal -2147024893
  COR_E_DIRECTORYNOTFOUND                                        corerror.h
# The specified path couldn't be found.
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x3
# for hex 0x3 / decimal 3
  ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND                                           winerror.h
# The system cannot find the path specified.
# 2 matches found for "0x80070003"
```

So it looks like Windows fails to find the system partition.

Comment: do you think that would be caused by lack of a storage device driver?

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's probably caused by the recent Windows partition migration from one hard drive to another. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Maybe a 3rd party partition tool can increase the size. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @magicandre1981 There's plenty of free space in the Windows partition (283 GB) What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the hidden SYSTEM partition, not the one which includes Windows