# Upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 While Multi-Booted With Linux

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-10, grub

My PC has two separate physical hard-drives in it, one with Windows 7, and one with Ubuntu Linux. In order to get the dual-boot set up to work properly, I set up GRUB to be installed on both hard drives, overwriting the Windows boot loader (and I assume the entire SYSTEM partition as well).

This is causing issues for my ability to upgrade to Windows 10. I am working with an eligible version of Windows 7, using the media creation tool. I have set up a thumb drive with the tool, that can be used either for booting, or upgrading within Windows 7/8. When I run setup.exe, it fails at the state where it checks if my PC can run Windows 10.

According to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/894321/unable-to-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-10), the error is caused by the application being unable to check how much space is available in the SYSTEM partition.

As far as I can think, there are two options to fix the issue:

1. Reinstall Windows 7, then proceed with the upgrade, possibly even removing the hard drive containing Linux entirely.
2. Restore the SYSTEM partition somehow and remove GRUB before proceeding with the upgrade.

I would prefer to make the second option work, but I'm not entirely sure how. [This forum thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/231133-recover-windows-7-100mb-system-reserved-partition.html) seems to have an answer, but I want to be sure this will fix the issue and avoid unnecessary risk of messing up my system.

Any insight on how to go about fixing the problem would be appreciated as I understand Linux much more than I do Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are only eligible for the free upgrade to Windows 10, if you perform the upgrade, from within an eligible installation of Windows.  It isn't clear what your question is though.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/226295/how-to-upgrade-a-linux-dual-boot-system-to-windows-10/

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the link! From looking at this it does appear I will need to do a fresh install of Windows 7 before upgrading to Windows 10, which will fix the issue and minimize unwanted carry-over as a bonus. I will post an answer to the question stating this as a solution after I successfully do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Using a Windows 7 installation DVD, I opened the repair menu and selected the option to repair boot problems. On reboot, Windows loaded without bringing up the GRUB menu, and the Windows 10 installation was able to proceed successfully.